# CentOS 7 boots too fast and network is not ready when executing cron scripts

Tags: centos, systemd

I have just upgraded from CentOS 6.5 to 7.0 and I am not too happy as the new `systemd` is probably giving me problems. It seems it is just simply booting too fast, starting up processes asynchronously and screwing up service dependencies.

For example I have a few scripts setup in `crond` which are triggered after a reboot:

```
@reboot    /root/scripts/check_gmail.sh
@reboot    /root/scripts/start_gps_listener.sh
```

This results in all kind of weird errors (only showing one of them):

```
Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://192.168.20.4:4001 
  (Network is unreachable) in /root/scripts/check_gmail.php on line 137
  ERROR: Network is unreachable (101)
```

In the above I am writing to a TCP socket. It is pretty clear to me that `crond` is started before the network is properly initialized as the `network is unreachable`.

The same thing goes with Apache and MySQL (MariaDB). MySQL is quite slow to startup (much data) meaning that both Apache and a lot of my `crond` startup scripts are failing as the MySQL database is not running when the scripts are being called.

I have tried to setup dependencies but without any luck; I have appended `network` and `mysql` services to `[Unit]` (as seen with `systemctl list-dependencies`). Ideally all services wait until MySQL is up and running:

```
vi /lib/systemd/system/httpd.service
  [Unit]
  Description=The Apache HTTP Server
  After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target network.service mysql.service

vi /lib/systemd/system/crond.service
  [Unit]
  Description=Command Scheduler
  After=syslog.target auditd.service systemd-user-sessions.service time-sync.target network.service mysql.service
```

When booting with the above I get the same errors. I also get the emails in `mailq` as the network/DNS is not ready when processing cron-scripts. A few minutes after startup they are sent correctly.

**Can anyone help getting this right by making sure the services are fired in the correct order?** It seems very wrong that it is so fast booting and ideally it did it the good old way, "launching one serice... wait... launching a new service... wait... so on).

Do note that I am not sure it is `systemd` that is my problem - it is just my theory of what I can read from the net.

Comment: Could you post the output of `grep -i concurrency  /etc/default/rcS`? I might be mixing up my init systems but I seem to recall that controls whether processes wait for one another to finish.

Comment: I have no files with `/etc/default/rc*`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know where the CentOS equivalent would be. I was thinking of what is described [here](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=31275) for Debian, which makes services start in parallel. There might be something similar set in your case.

Comment: Try adding `Requires=network.target` to the units above.

Comment: Still same problem after inserted `Requires=network.target` in to `/lib/systemd/system/crond.service`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After a lot more reading I found the solution that works for me.

I read this guide, [Running Services After the Network is up](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/). A little quote from the guide:

> *This will ensure that all configured network devices are up and have an IP address assigned before boot continues.*

This is exactly what I wanted so I enabled this service and set the a dependency rule in the service file for `crond`:

```
[root@srv]# systemctl enable NetworkManager-wait-online

[root@srv]# vi /lib/systemd/system/crond.service
  Requires=network.target
  After=syslog.target auditd.service systemd-user-sessions.service time-sync.target network.target mysqld.service
```

As `mysqld` is still based on the old `init.d` I needed to create a `systemd` service as suggested here, [systemctl enable differs from systemctl start](https://superuser.com/a/384670/374691):

```
[root@srv]# vi /lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service
  [Unit]
  Description=MySQL Server
  After=network.target
  [Service]
  Type=forking
  ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/mysql start
  ExecStop=/etc/rc.d/init.d/mysql stop
  [Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target

[root@srv]# systemctl daemon-reload
[root@srv]# chkconfig mysql off
[root@srv]# systemctl enable mysqld
```

And finally setup the Apache service to startup *after* MySQL:

```
[root@srv]# vi /lib/systemd/system/httpd.service
  Requires=mysqld.service
  After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target mysqld.service
```

This works for me at least.

I have used these commands to check it afterwards where I clearly can see that network is started up prior to at least MySQL and Apache. I though cannot see the `crond` anywhere but I can see it is working in my scripts:

```
[root@srv]# systemd-analyze critical-chain
  multi-user.target @10.510s
    + httpd.service @10.344s +165ms
      + mysqld.service @9.277s +1.065s
        + network.target @9.273s
          + network.service @8.917s +355ms
            + iptables.service @444ms +157ms
              + basic.target @443ms
                [CUT]
```

A couple of other useful commands I used are:

```
# See exactly what takes how long (who to blame for the delay)
[root@srv]# systemd-analyze blame

# Check available names that can be used in the service files
[root@srv]# systemctl list-unit-files
```

If any one can see any better way to do this then please share.

Comment: +1 for posting the commands you used to debug this. I was able to resolve a really nasty knot of problems with `systemd-analyze critical-chain`. Not only am I going to use that often, but I am suddenly sold on `systemd`. Thanks!

Comment: You should not modify services files managed by your distribution package manager.
Instead you'd better use drop-in configuration files. See the answer to  [How do I override or configure systemd services ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/659267/how-do-i-override-or-configure-systemd-services)